# How to automatically generate a new Template when a Model is added

Tags: python, django

I'm building an application in Django, I have a Model called User and a View called profile. When I add an User object, I want to automatically generate a new template username-profile.html correspondent to the new User object. Is possible to do that or I'll have to manually create a new template for each User object?

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=220)
```

views.py:

```
class Profile(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):             
        return render(request, 'profile.html')
```

Comment: Why do you need a separate template for each user?

Comment: Your idea looks bad, if you will need to change html code or some else.

Comment: What you probably actually want to do is render  your single profile.html template with a templating language like jinja2, so that the one file can work for all your users

Comment: Hmm..  I didn't know about those templating languages, I'll try it, thanks

Comment: I took a look at jinja, I don't think this gonna work for me. My app is a website for services advertising, so each user must have a HTML page that  shows the services that s /he provides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you can create a url dispatcher like

```
url(r'^(P<user_name>\w+)/$', views.your_view),
```

and in your view you can render only one template instead of create many templates so your view will look like:

```
def your_view(request, user_name):
    user = get_object_or_404(username=user_name)
    context = {
        '':user.info
    }
    return render(request, 'your_app/template.html')
```

so in your template.html render your user info. If you didn't understand read this [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial03/)